# How to make GREP match everything between two markers, regardless the Forced Line Brake occurance

Tags: adobe-indesign, character-styles, grep

I'm wondering if it's possible to make GREP "jump over" the Forced Line Brake (FLB), while he is searching for particular keyword.

I have a text frame containing multiple Companies described by three categories:

```
    1. Company's Name
    2. Website
    3. Short Description.
```

Every category is marked in the text by it's marker (a keyword) on the beginning of it:

```
    MARKER1 Dreamworks Studios [FLB]
    MARKER2 www_dreamworks_xxx/info/info [FLB]
    MARKER3 company that produces movies [PR]
    MARKER1 Coca-Cola Company [FLB]
    MARKER2 www_cocacola_xxx/info/info [FLB]
    MARKER3 company that produces drinks [PR]
    ...etc.
```

Now, each of those three categories should have separate CHARACTER STYLE applied with use of GREP. I want GREP to search trough the text till he finds specific marker and to apply desired STYLE to everything... untill the next marker:

```
    everything between MARKER1 and MARKER2 should get STYLE1
    everything between MARKER2 and MARKER3 should get STYLE2
    everything between MARKER3 and MARKER1 should get STYLE3
```

And that's quite easy... untill I have to use more FLB-s between markers:

```
    MARKER1 Dreamworks [FLB]
    Studios [FLB]
    MARKER2 www_dreamworks_xxx/ [FLB]
    info/info [FLB]
    MARKER3 company that[FLB]
    produces [FLB]
    movies [PR]
    ...etc.
```

When the text looks like above, all my concepts for GREP sentences fail. I stumbled here upon this useful sentence, which is good if the text looks like in the first example (without multiple FLB-s between markers), or if used with only one style and one category. Here is how I'm using it to apply STYLE1 to the part of text of first category:

```
Apply: 
    STYLE1
to Text: 
    ^.*?((MARKER2)|$)
```

But when I use similar sentence with next category (changing only the marker) it doesn't work properly. because of those additional FLB-s.

So I repeat my question: **is it possible to make GREP "jump over" the Forced Line Brake (FLB), when it is searching for particular keyword?**

Answer (score -1):

You need a conditional.

In pseudo code:

If this state is true (searching for your keyword)
Then jump over FLBs

Else

Don't jump of FLBs

And probably put this in a loop so that it solves throughout the doc.

Apparently GREP has the ability to deal with conditionals... maybe.

Comment: In terms of logic - I agree with you. The same way I was approaching this problem. But HOW on Earth make this logic work in Indesign's GREP? I have been searching for GREP conditionals commands trough the web and nothing. I only got the "OR" command, which I have incorporated into my logic structure, and into GREP commands, but that haven't worked. Can You help me more directly? Which commands of GREP I should look up for this conditional searching?

Or maybe there is another option? I was thinking about applying a set of 3 PARAGRAPH STYLES to a text frame (with "next style"). WhatDoYouThink?